# How is $\nabla_XY$ calculated along $X$?

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

Let $X,Y:M\to TM$ be vector fields. I know the expression of the covariant derivative $\nabla_XY|_p$ as a limit given its parallel transport on a curve *along the direction of $X$*.
$$\nabla_XY|_p=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\Pi_{-tX}(Y_{\phi^X(t)})-Y_p}{t}$$
the map $\Pi_{-tX}$ being a parallel transport $\Pi_{-tX}:T_{\phi^X(t)}M\to T_pM$, the curve satisfying:
$$\phi^X(0)=p \; \; ; \; \; (\phi^X(0))'=X_p$$
so what curve is $\phi^X(t)$ exactly? an integral "flow" curve of $X$ passing through $p$? a geodesic in the direction of $X$? or what?

Comment: $\phi^X(t)$ is just a differential curve with $\phi^X(0)=p \; \; ; \; \; (\phi^X(0))'=X_p$. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative#In_differential_geometry).

Comment: @KurtG. thanks for the reply. so it can be any curve as long as it's in the direction of $X_p$ at $p$. because any curve satisfying these two conditions will look similar or close to any other curve satisfying the same conditions if we zoomed enough near $p$.